# sockjs-client в ie и edge

Tags: javascript, websocket, redux-middleware

Друзья фронтэндеры, прошу помочь бэку.

На фронт-части проекта использую библиотеку sockjs-client для websocket. Написал для этого небольшой middleware (часть кода ниже).
Проблема в том, что это прекрасно работает в chrome и firefox, но не в ie и edge.
В них не отрабатывает событие по `client.onConnect = () => onOpen(store);`

Если включить дебаг, то в microsoft-браузерах, видно только одно сообщение в консоли: `Opening Web Socket...`
Тогда как в других браузерах за ним следует `Web Socket Opened...`, далее `>>> CONNECT`, подписки и т.д.

```
....
import {CompatClient, IMessage, Stomp} from "@stomp/stompjs";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
....
export const socketMiddleware = (function () {
  let client: CompatClient;
  client = Stomp.over(function () {
      return new SockJS(WS_ROOT);
  });
  ....
  const tryConnect = (store: Store) => {
      client.onWebSocketClose = () => {
          onClose(store);
          setTimeout(() => tryConnect(store), 5000);
      };
      client.onConnect = () => onOpen(store);
      // client.debug = console.log;
      client.debug = ()=>{};
      client.activate();
  };
  ....
  return (store: any) => (next: any) => (action: any) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SOCKS_CONNECT:
            if (connected) {
                return;
            }
            tryConnect(store);
            break;
  ....
}
```

Comment: разработчики ие всегда отличались уникальностью и то что в других браузерах уже давно работает, там не факт что есть даже в зародыше. Вы берите по частям ваш код и гуглите (или https://caniuse.com/) его на поддержку в необходимой вам минимальной версии ие или edge и пишите уже с этим учетом.

Comment: За ресурс респект. 

В ie и edge эта библиотека должна работать: на гитхабе указана совместимость. Косяк где-то у меня.
Вопрос написал на удачу: вдруг кто-то сталкивался с таким поведением.